# Collections.shuffle doesn't work for Processing.js?

Tags: java, processing, processing.js

Getting this error: "uncaught exception: Processing.js: Unable to execute pjs sketch: ReferenceError: Collections is not defined" even though I have imported the lib

```
import java.util.Collections;
```

Thoughts?

Comment: That's the point of Processing.js, yes :)

Answer (score 2):

Per http://processingjs.org/reference/, Processing.js doesn't support java.util.Collections, only (most of) the base language plus a few things out of the Collections library such as ArrayList and HashMap.